# jenkins Active Directory with ldaps failed with "JDK TrustStore"

Tags: jenkins

My settings of AD on jenkins have ever work well. One day it failed. And I can not set it correct any more.  The strange behavior is, if I set "TLS Configuration" as "(unsecure)Trust all Certificates" and press the "Test Domain", it shows success.

If I set as "JDK Trustore", it shows `simple bind failed: example.com.tw:636`.
The detail said "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".

After trace, jenkins is launch with systemd with the options in /etc/systemd/system/jenkins.service.

```
Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE=/etc/ssl/certs/example.ca.jks"
Environment="JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=XXX"
```

I've use the InstallCert tool to insert the example.com:636's cert into the jks file. But still don't know what's the fail reason.

Any hint to trace the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins's "Active Directory" plugin use the $JAVA_HOME/jre/security/cacerts

Because the systemd file not specific JAVA_HOME, so, I check which version java is running and its cacerts file's location

```
$ which java
/usr/bin/java
$ realpath /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el8_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java
$  realpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el8_4.x86_64/jre/lib/security/cacerts
/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts
```

Use java keytool command to read the content and check example.com is not exist there.

```
$ keytool --list -v -keystore /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts -storepass changeit |& less
```